# How to redesign confusion matrices from Ecognition with python and seaborn?

Tags: python, accuracy, ecognition, confusion-matrix, scikit-learn

I am using eCognition manual classification as a baseline for performance comparison with other 3D classification methods. For each method, I am creating confusion matrices in python with sklearn and seaborn. I am trying to transform the confusion matrices resulting from the eCognition accuracy assessment (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWlH4.png)) into seaborn generated confusion matrices so they all have the same pattern for publication i.e with the same seaborn colour palette **as in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5mFb.png)**.

[image: eCognition confusion matrix output from accuracy assessment]
[image: Confusion matrix with python and seaborn]

The code I used to create the confusion matrices for the other methods is below:

Here, the **y_true** is the annotated data (ground-truthed) and the **y_pred** is the result from the classification. The input is a csv file where each pixel has its manual annotation (y_true) value and its y_pred value.

```
def plot_cmatrix(y_true, y_pred, figsize=(10,10)):
    data = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=np.unique(y_true), index = np.unique(y_true))
    df_cm.index.name = 'Actual class'
    df_cm.columns.name = 'Predicted class'
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
    # plt.title("Model F \nAccuracy: {0:.3f}".format(accuracy_score(y_true,y_pred)))
    plt.title("Model F")
    sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
    sns.heatmap(df_cm, cmap="Blues", annot=True, fmt='d', annot_kws={"size":16})
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    print("True negative: ", tn,"False Positive: ", fp, "False Negative:", fn,"True Positive: ", tp)
```

So I want to apply the function with eCognition classification results, but I am not sure how to get information on y_pred and y_true information there. This brings me to the three questions below:

Would anyone know how can I get these values from the classification in eCognition?

Any suggestions are welcomed

If you need any further information please feel free to contact me

Comment: Interesting questions. I would recommend including only the first question.  The second question should be on a separate post.

Comment: Are you having a difficult time finding the corresponding predicted values from the ecog output? My initial thought is to use the ground truth data to sample the predicted output.

Comment: Hi @Aaron thank you for your reply. Yes. That is a good idea. Can you recommend any tips or tutorials on how to get the ground truth vs. predicted output from ecognition?